# Javascript condition is not working with OR IF AND

Tags: javascript

Not able to find out what i have written incorrect in following code so that it is not returning false. While debugging found that there is error in

```
((typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo') && date1 === '')
```

as it has below values during execution

```
radioValue = "scheduleademo", date1 = ""
```

Complete if part:

```js
if (name === '' || emailID === '' || phone === '' || companyname === '' || noofemployees === null || message === '' ||
  radioValue === '' || (typeof radioValue === 'undefined') || ((typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo') && date1 === '')) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo'` Looks like typo, that cannot be a `typeof`, To test against that string, use `radioValue === 'scheduleademo'` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you compare the type instead of a value in `(typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo')`. You probably wanted to compare the values like `(radioValue === 'scheduleademo')`

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) in JavaScript returns the type of a given operand. 
Since `radioValue` is assigned a string, `typeof radioValue` will return `'string'`. That is the reason why `(typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo')` will always return false.

Complete corrected code:

```
if (name === '' || emailID === '' || phone === '' || companyname === '' || noofemployees === null || message === '' ||
  radioValue === '' || (typeof radioValue === 'undefined') || ((radioValue === 'scheduleademo') && date1 === '')) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` is a unary operatory it only returns you the type, example:

```
typeof "scheduleademo" //"string"
typeof 2 //"number"
```

you should use it to check for type of your variable not to match strings

`typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo'` **should be** `radioValue === 'scheduleademo'` or `typeof radioValue === 'undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

typeof returns the primitive type of the variable. Can be 'Array', 'string', 'number',. not the actual value.

```
typeof radioValue === 'scheduleademo'
```

This will always be false. For ever and ever. Please check the typeof definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

In this case it should be returns `false` because typeof property will return the type of the data such as Array, String, Object etc.

`typeof radioValue` should be returns it's type not the value. `scheduleademo` is not an valid type so instead of that u can use `(typeof radioValue === 'string')` to check whether it's match the required condition.

please note in here i'm assuming `scheduleademo` is an string.

**Corrected Answer:**

`if (name === '' || emailID === '' || phone === '' || companyname === '' || noofemployees === null || message === '' ||
  radioValue === '' || (typeof radioValue === 'undefined') || ((typeof radioValue === 'string') && date1 === '')) {
  return false;`
}